gunzip file to mysql - run in background over ssh?
I have some large SQL files to import to a MySQL database. They must be imported directly from the gz file because there's not a huge amount of disk space on the server, so unzipping first and importing the .sql file is not possible.
So I'm using this command (via SSH on a remote server) to do it:
gunzip -c test.sql.gz | mysql test_db
However, I'm concerned that if my SSH connection drops, it'll kill this half way through. How can I send that command to the background so that even if I lose SSH connection, it'll continue running and finish?

You could unzip on a server with free space and import from there, have you considered this ?

@ErgestBasha Things are pretty locked down so it's tricky. I had previously been trying to get SSH tunnelling via sockets working to do what you suggest, but it's just massively overcomplicated for what I was hoping would have a fairly simple solution :)
In short, I've considered it but I don't think it's a straightforward option in this case.

There are tools like nohup, screen, tmux but I have no experience with any of those.

Ended up doing this with a bash script.
vim importdata.sh
#!/bin/bash

gunzip -c /test.sql.gz | mysql test_db

Gave permissions to run: chmod a+x importdata.sh, and ran the command with ./importdata.sh & to send the script to the background.
Seems to be working.

If you need it to continue running if your network connection drops, I would use tmux. That's a very useful tool for any software professional to know, in many different circumstances.

This is a corrected version of my original comment. Running the script in the background allows you to reuse the terminal for other commands, but that's all. It'll kill the command if you close the terminal, and it won't change anything regarding network connection dropping.

@ÁlvaroGonzález Are you sure? My terminal dropped out and the script was still running when I reconnected??

Well... You're making me doubt. I don't have SSH here to test now. I typically do nohup ./importdata.sh & for this use case.
